# What do you call somebody who belongs to a sector?

Tags: suffixes

### Sectors could be any of the following:

- alpha, beta, gamma sector
- fourth, fifth sector on a CD track

### Do I say:

- sectorian (Christian)
- sectrant (celebrant, immigrant)
- sectorese (Japanese)
- sectoran (German, American) (might be similar to sectorian)
- sectorean (European) (might be similar to sectorian)
- sectorish (Danish, Finnish)

### Context:

I want to make a keyword in Magic: The Gathering and it's usage will be like this:

```
Creature Name UUU
Gamma *Sectorian* (This creature belongs to the Gamma sector)
```

The usage would be similar to Daybound and Nightbound:
https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Daybound_and_Nightbound

Specifically, i'm looking for something that will work with the Space sculptor clause on the Space Beleren card.
[image]

Comment: I don't think there is such a word. People belong to groups and organisations, not sectors - or they "work in the supply sector".

Comment: In your particular case, is a sector a geographical area, or is the classification based on something else (job, race, etc)? You could use something like "sector-person" ("sectorman" might be a more traditional form, c.f. Frenchman, foundryman, but is gender-specific). Otherwise, it's a fantasy setting, so you can choose whichever sounds nicest.

Comment: Could they be [sectoral](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sectoral)? Or you could make one up: a sectorant, a sectorist.

Comment: *Sectorian* was used [once in the late 19th century](https://www.loc.gov/item/08004707/) to describe a system of handrailing using [geometric sectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector).  There is nothing to stop you re-using it for your purposes, if you do not mind it sounding a little like a mispronunciation of *sectarian*.

Comment: _Don't_ make one up. Language is meant to facilitate clear communication, and a _sectorant/sectorist_  sounds like an old name for a surgeon. This is a lexical gap; take Kate's advice.

Comment: @StuartF thank you for pointing out that that wasn't clear. i would like to focus on the location aspect of sector, i think. i've revised my question to reflect this and added some more context.